# Explanation of converting a look-at / direction vector to quaternion rotation?

Tags: mathematics

**Can someone please explain the math behind converting a direction-vector or lookAt-vector into a quaternion rotation?**

**What I am trying to do?**
I am trying to create a custom aim-constraint for a DCC (Maya. Also, Maya already provides one but I have reason to write a custom one). I have the world-space positions of eye and destination using which I can calculate direction vector but I need to calculate quaternion/euler rotation to rotate the object so that I can look at the destination.

**What I found so far?**
There are couple of thread I found and read so far but some provide engine based approach, some do not provide explanation of math behind it and a few didn't work when converted into code.
I am listing few of them here (for reference)

1. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149006/direction-vector-to-quaternion
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873996/converting-a-direction-vector-to-a-quaternion-rotation
3. https://answers.unity.com/questions/631836/how-i-can-converting-a-direction-vector-to-quatern.html
4. http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/
5. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765799/convert-direction-vector-to-euler-angles

**What I am Not looking for?**

- way of calculating quaternion rotation from a (transformation) matrix.
- engine based approach eg: `Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up)`

Thank you!

Comment: Here you go: http://lolengine.net/blog/2014/02/24/quaternion-from-two-vectors-final

Comment: @lightxbulb: Thanks for pointing me to the link. I tried the code but it doesn't give correct rotation for some reason. For example if v = (0,1,0) and u= (5,0,0), quaternion value function gives is : 
'Quaternion : ', 0.7071067811865475, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7071067811865475
'Euler : ', 90.0, 0.0, 0.0 (in degrees)
which is not correct.

Comment: Or you're reading it wrong and it is 0,0,90. Which would be correct.